# To know the accurate key breakpoint in bootstrap grid system

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap for my home page layout. I have got one column of 9 units for my content and one 3 units column for my sidebar. The div inside the sidebar is position:fixed. For smaller screens bootstrap send my side bar to the bottom, that is ok. However, at that moment I need my sidebar position relative.
I am using JavaScript to check the width of the screen to change the position property, but I am guessing that bootstrap is going to send my sidebar to the bottom when the screen is lesser than 972px. How can I really know the accurate width which bootstrap will send my sidebar to the bottom? Appreciate any help? Thanks. Other approaches are welcome.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">

                <div class="content"></div>


            </div>


            <div class="col-md-3">


                 <div class="sidebar"></div>


            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

The script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(window).width() > 972) {
            $('.sidebar').css('position', 'fixed');

        }              
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Bootstrap front page it has the info for this.

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

There is also the xs which is  `< 768px`.

To get full control use all `lg, md, sm and xs`, and set what you want for each device/screen size.
Just using one like lg will allow things to change when resized.

Adding a **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/xnb2gn6m/embedded/result/)** to help re your second question.

I have set up a full screen Fiddle for you, resize the window and see how the two areas stay side by side when you resize.
That is controlling it as you want I think.

```
<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 bg-success block">

</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 bg-primary block">

</div>
```

**Added**

Hit F12

[image]

Comment: The thing is when I shrink the browser to realize which width it will send the div below, It happens when my $(window).width() is about 970. So I don't understand. It does not make sense with Bootstrap front page info.

Comment: Thanks, Angular. But I think I was not clear with my question. What I want is change the position of a div inside of my sidebar from fixed to relative when bootstrap send this column to the bottom. Because if it continues being fixed it overlays my footer. So I want to know the exact moment that that column goes to the bottom to change the position to be relative using media query. In my screen it happens when view port get 972px. But i can not trust it gonna happen in all devices. I wanna be sure when bootstrap always change that behavior.

Comment: **Added above**.     Does this help?

Comment: Thanks. Actually I could realize that when i use $(window).width() it is not accurate. Maybe it does not include the scrollbar width. The columns are really spliting up at 992px. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @DiegoBayona You want `window.innerWidth`

Comment: Sounds like you are getting there.   If you want to add scroll on the x axis to a contained area, you can add this in the css class  `overflow-x: scroll;`

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap breakpoint you are using is md (Medium devices).

So when the screen width is >= 992px it will be side-by-side with your main content div. When it is <= 991px it will drop below.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: The thing is when I shrink the browser to realize which width it will send the div below, It happens when my $(window).width() is about 970. So I don't understand. It does not make sense with Bootstrap front page info. (992px)

Comment: Isn't that just your jQuery setting the position fixed that's causing that. Comment out your jQuery function and try again.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I could realize that when i use $(window).width() it is not accurate. Maybe it does not include the scrollbar width. The columns are really spliting up at 992px. Appreciate your help